# Why didn't I get the message "mqtt problem" micropython

Tags: python, mqtt, esp32, micropython, publisher

I am writing code on esp32 to be a MQTT publisher and when I run the program on esp32 I get a message on terminal "success send a data" but when I see on my subscriber program on python I didn't get any message. I think the problem was from token but when you see they have a same token.

Code on esp32 as a publisher :

```
import network 
import json
import time
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient

net = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
net.active(True)

while True:
    try:
        net.connect('Office_CWG', 'Unais2020')
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
    time.sleep(1)
    if net.isconnected():
        print('Connected') 
        break
    
broker = 'broker.hivemq.com' 
client = MQTTClient('vito', broker)
client.connect()

def send(topic, pesan):
  client.publish(topic, data)
  print ('success sent a data')
  
sensor = {
    'topic': 'active_1',
    'current': '25',
    'volt': '220',
    'frekuensi': '50',
    'activePower': '100',
    'energy': '90',
    'ambienceTemperature': '36',
    'jointTemperature': '36'
}
data = json.dumps(sensor)
topic = 'vito'
send(data, topic)
```

Code on vscode with python as a subscriber :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json


def connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):  # rc = return code if 1 = error
    if rc == 0:
        rc = "success"
    else:
        rc = "error"
    print("Connected to mqtt "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("vito")


def message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    # pesan = json.loads(str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    # print(pesan['data'])
    # # print(pesan['message']['alertJoint'])


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = connect
client.on_message = message

client.connect("broker.hivemq.com")
client.loop_forever()
```

I expected the message would be sent but actual result didn't get anything.
d

Comment: You are calling `send(data, topic)` but the function definition is `def send(topic, pesan)` (note that `topic` is first...).

Comment: You may also need to encode your topic and message. Here's an example: `client.publish(MQTT_TOPIC.encode('utf-8'), (MQTT_CLIENT_ID + "\r\njoined the chat.").encode('utf-8'))`